# Cast string+ntext to nvarchar error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to cast a string and a column value concatenated with the following sql commant:

```
 CAST('Strign:'+[KlirAn] as NVARCHAR(max))
```

After executing this command i get the following error:

```
    Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The data types varchar and ntext are incompatible in the add operator.
```

Any help please?

Comment: What is the datatype of KlirAn??

Comment: I assume [KlirAn] is ntext ?

Comment: Please provide the DB schema for table for column **`[KlirAn]`**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try the following:

```
'String:'+ CAST([KlirAn] as NVARCHAR(max))
```

Answer (score 4):

Try this

```
SELECT
  'String:'+CONVERT(NVARCHAR(max),[KlirAn])
FROM table
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `'Strign:'` is `varchar` and `[KlirAn]` is `NTEXT`, so a possible fix is:

```
CAST('Strign:'+CAST([KlirAn] AS VARCHAR(max)) as NVARCHAR(max))
```

As @Damien_The_Unbeliever states in a comment, it's not the most brilliant way of doing it, but it works.

You could also take advantage of the implicit conversion in SQL (VARCHAR TO NVARCHAR) and simply:

```
'Strign:' + CAST([KlirAn] AS NVARCHAR(max))
```

BTW, you should take into consideration:

- The [+ (String Concatenation) (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) doesn't work on SQL Server for the
  ntext data type.
- In fact, ntext is deprecated:

> ntext, text, and image data types will be removed in a future version 
>   of MicrosoftSQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

Comment: Why would you cast `KlirAn`, an `NTEXT` column, to **`VARCHAR`**, just to later, after you've mangled the string, to cast the result back to `NVARCHAR`? Why not keep it `N` throughout?